# JQuery show/hide toggle with multiple buttons with same name

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm new to JQuery, and am slowly muddling my way through but am really stumped on this :(

I have a page with multiple 'more information' buttons, which when clicked toggle information (which is different for each button)

However, when I click on say the second 'more information' button it just toggles the first button multiple times (the number of 'more information' buttons.

I've tried various suggested solutions, but can't seem to get it to work properly :)

This is the code I have at the moment:

http://pastebin.com/SSxc09Gy

Any help would be amazing and gratefully received!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You seem to be binding the same event multiple times.. One instance of it is good enough.. If there are 5 elements with a particular class , you need not bind it 5 times for each element . Just once is sufficient

Comment: And your HTML markup is supposed to be outside the body.. Can you create  working version of it at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you for the binding thing - didn't realise it wasn't needed multiple times. Massive help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit cleaned up [version](http://jsfiddle.net/NHGj8/) of your pastebin example.

The cleaned up version removes the duplicate deceleration of styles and javascript and the html/head markup inside the table. Are you loading this data in from another source? Is that why the html/head/body section are there?

Looks like in your second set of mark up you need to update the href attribute to #collapse2 for the button and the id for the div which contains the other info. The javascript you use looks for that href attribute to determine which div to expand.

Should end up like this:

```
<section class="round-border">
    <div>
        <button href="#collapse2" class="nav-toggle">More Information</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" style="display:none">
        <div id="justify" style="width:574px;text-align:left">
            <p>Second lot of information</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You could also change your markup and javascript in a way that doesn't require you to be tied to unique collapse id's.

If you change your markup as such, by making the div id "collapse1" into a class of "collapse", you can get javascript to walk up the dom to find the element containing the button and the div to be toggled using jQuery's [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, then finding the collapseable div element within using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/). This also nicely shows how awesome jQuery's method chaining is.

**new markup**

```
<td colspan="4" style="text-align:right;">
    <section class="round-border">
        <div>
            <button class="nav-toggle">More Information</button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse hide">
            <div id="justify" style="width:574px;text-align:left">
                <p>Second lot of information</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</td>
```

**new js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.round-border').find('.collapse').slideToggle();

        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text == "More Information" ? "Hide" : "More Information");
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHGj8/1/) with alternative solution

Note that this method is more computationally intensive since jQuery is doing a lot more searching of the dom, but it makes it a bit easier to maintain your content since you don't have to worry about keeping track of collapse id numbers. If you're doing this only in a handful of places without a lot of elements, then the negative from the extra computation shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Thank you SO much - been tearing my hair out for literally hours and it works perfectly now :D

Comment: @GemmaWood Yeah it's the little things that can sometimes cause the biggest headaches. Take a look at the alternative method to doing the same thing I posted.